# Which approach to use when dealing with images in a web application

Tags: java, database, image, jsp

I am working on a web application, using JSP and Servlets, I was retreiving pictures as a string which contains the path of that picture.

```
while(rset.next())
{ %>
     <img src='<%rset.getString(1)%>' />
<%  }
```

And the table in the database would be like this.

```
id ---- image_path

1.....images/aaa.png

2.....images/bbb.png
```

So what I'm doing here is actually getting the path of the image, not the image itself, the images are inside a folder called images.

But later on, I found another way which actually stores images in a database.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pictures VALUES(?,?)");
  File file = new File("C:/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/webapps/CodingDiaryExample/images/5.jpg");
  FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
  ps.setInt(1,8);
  ps.setBinaryStream(2,fs,fs.available());
  int i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Best approach for which problem?

Comment: What is your concrete question? 'Dealing with images' can mean many things.

Comment: Displaying images in your web page, lets say I click a button, I need a specific image, so the query will be like... "where image_name= ..", now here, should I store the imgage in the database, or store its path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Getting images from Web Application is Good compared with fetching from Database.
2. OR if you have more number of images,then store in a FTP and fetch based on pah.

Comment: in your case already image is available in web application path so when you read image as Object(File), it will create extra object and passing the object will be more resource usage. What kind of image you want to save and show which are related to application or something else ?

Comment: And how many images you are having?

Comment: Lets say that my web app is based on images, a lot... Its not 1 or 2, its many, like fetching up to 10 images together.

Comment: see there are two kind of images one is for application and another one  is for business. Example 1.logo,headers etc(for application) 2,shoes,shirts,pen,jewels(as products very often it will be changed). so what kind of images you are having to show.

Comment: static images, ill keep them in the folder, private images for users, in database, I got the idea :D THANKS :D